# Android database not inserting entries

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-database

I am trying to make simple database entry app where 
When I click on button to initiate The Enter function  it should insert some  values into the database.
But it's not working.

The main Activity  button onclick function ( variable  for database are

```
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private AppDBHelper mhelper;
```

Globally 
:

```
public void Enter(View V){
    mhelper=new AppDBHelper(this);
 db=mhelper.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues val=new ContentValues();
 val.put(AppContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT,"thatsall");
 val.put(AppContract.TaskEntry.ID,"4");
 val.put(AppContract.TaskEntry.STATE,"notStarted");
long err= this.db.insert(AppContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,null,val);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"db ="+ err,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
db.close();
}
```

The appContract :

```
  public class AppContract {          
public static. final String  DB_NAME = "storage.db"; 
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {
public static final String TABLE = "tasks";
public static final String CONTENT ="content";
public static final String ID ="Id";

public static final String STATE = "state";
  }
```

AppDBhelper:

```
   public class AppDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
public AppDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, AppContract.DB_NAME, null, AppContract.DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + AppContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " (  " +
        AppContract.TaskEntry.ID + " TEXT , " +
        AppContract.TaskEntry.STATE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
        AppContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT+ "  TEXT )";

    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AppContract.TaskEntry.TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
 }
```

DataProvider :

```
  public class DataProvider extends ContentProvider
 {
    private AppDBHelper adbhelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    adbhelper= new AppDBHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}


@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

 }
```

The db.insert in mainActivity always returns -1  what am I doing wrong ?

Edit :here is the log for the code

> ```
>   10-04 15:32:40.610 9415 9445 I     Process                                      Sending signal. PID: 9415 SIG: 9
>   10-04 15:32:50.538 10144 10144 I   art com.mycompany.myapp4                     Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>    10-04 15:32:50.631 10144 10144 D   TidaProvider com.mycompany.myapp4            TidaProvider()
> 10-04 15:32:50.647 10144 10144 V   BoostFramework com.mycompany.myapp4          BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@9eeb3f3
> 10-04 15:32:50.723 10144 10144 W   System com.mycompany.myapp4                  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp4-1/lib/arm64
>  10-04 15:32:50.748 10144 10144 W   art com.mycompany.myapp4                     Class adrt.ADRT failed lock verification and will run slower.
>  10-04 15:32:50.748 10144 10144 W   art com.mycompany.myapp4                     Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
>  10-04 15:32:50.748 10144 10144 W   art com.mycompany.myapp4                     and incorrect proguard optimizations.
>  10-04 15:32:50.832 10144 10144 D   AccessibilityManager com.mycompany.myapp4     current package=com.mycompany.myapp4, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=true, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
>  10-04 15:32:50.839 10144 10144 V   BoostFramework com.mycompany.myapp4          BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@92c7fe3
>  10-04 15:32:50.839 10144 10144 V   BoostFramework com.mycompany.myapp4          BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@37bcde0
>  10-04 15:32:50.895 10144 10144 E   HAL com.mycompany.myapp4                     PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
>  10-04 15:32:50.895 10144 10144 E   HAL com.mycompany.myapp4                     PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
> 10-04 15:32:50.895 10144 10144 E   HAL com.mycompany.myapp4                     PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
> 10-04 15:32:50.895 10144 10144 E   HAL com.mycompany.myapp4                     PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
> 10-04 15:32:50.895 10144 10144 E   HAL com.mycompany.myapp4                     PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
> 10-04 15:32:50.895 10144 10144 E   HAL com.mycompany.myapp4                     PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
> 10-04 15:32:50.920 10144 10171 I   Adreno com.mycompany.myapp4                  QUALCOMM build                   : 01d2d27, I3d52eaf367
> 10-04 15:32:50.920 10144 10171 I   Adreno com.mycompany.myapp4                  Build Date                       : 12/10/16
>  10-04 15:32:50.920 10144 10171 I   Adreno com.mycompany.myapp4                  OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
>   10-04 15:32:50.920 10144 10171 I   Adreno com.mycompany.myapp4                  Local Branch                     :
>  10-04 15:32:50.920 10144 10171 I   Adreno com.mycompany.myapp4                  Remote Branch                    :
>   10-04 15:32:50.920 10144 10171 I   Adreno com.mycompany.myapp4                  Remote Branch                    :
>    10-04 15:32:50.920 10144 10171 I   Adreno com.mycompany.myapp4                  Reconstruct Branch               :
>    10-04 15:32:50.925 10144 10171 I   OpenGLRenderer com.mycompany.myapp4          Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>    10-04 15:32:50.925 10144 10171 D   OpenGLRenderer com.mycompany.myapp4          Swap behavior 1
>     10-04 15:32:51.775 10144 10144 V   BoostFramework com.mycompany.myapp4          BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@76280cc
>     10-04 15:32:51.864 10144 10144 E   SQLiteLog com.mycompany.myapp4               (1) table tasks has no column named id
>    10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          Error inserting state=notStarted content=thatsall id=4
>     10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table tasks has no column named id (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tasks(state,content,id) VALUES (?,?,?)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>    10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>  10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>  10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1470)
>  10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at com.mycompany.myapp4.MainActivity.Enter(MainActivity.java:53)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>  10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4702)
> 10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
> 10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22295)
> 10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
> 10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>  10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
> 10-04 15:32:51.865 10144 10144 E   SQLiteDatabase com.mycompany.myapp4          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
>   10-04 15:32:51.878 10144 10144 I   Toast com.mycompany.myapp4                   Show toast from OpPackageName:com.mycompany.myapp4, PackageName:com.mycompany.myapp4
> ```
>
> Also  I have removed the T_id  from the  db , and the id  variable is not for primary key purpose since  I don't need any primary key

Edit 2:  I found the problem !!
I wasn't actually updating the db version  and was only changing the db structure  this caused the error  .
Thanks to all for helpIng

Comment: shouldn't we declare the t_id in the TaskEntry please ?

Comment: There should be an error message in Logcat, it will contain more details.

Comment: why do you have t_id? BaseColumn (in TaskEntry) has _ID field already.

Comment: Not acutally an answer to your question but I recommend using Room for accessing DB in Android: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: you can use insertOrThrow instead of insert, and capture the exception which will explain the reason.

Comment: @Minhal ali khan it will solve u r issue http://www.codebind.com/android-tutorials-and-examples/android-sqlite-tutorial-example/